# Python: fastest way to find the largest element is a DS smaller than a given value then delete it

Tags: python, data-structures

If we use `list`, then finding the element takes `O(log n)` time but deleting takes linear time.

If we use `set`, then deleting takes constant time but finding the element takes linear time (I believe there is no build-in function for such purpose and we need to loop over all elements).

Is there a suitable data structure in python to achieve both steps in `O(log n)` time?

Comment: Perhaps this concept of binary search trees as well as hash tables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251690/data-structure-with-amortized-o1-delete-and-olog-n-search

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Built in, I don't know, you'll find a library for everything. But you should check out Binary Trees. Elements can be found in `O(log n)`, but making one takes time, so don't use it untill you plan searching multiple times.

Also there are varieties, to handle strings, objects, not just numbers. Radix tree, Red Black Tree, etc.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)
[Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-data-structure/)

I found a library for that: [binarytree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binarytree-module-in-python/).